# Spring saml integration with IDP server got SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

As a service provider, I'm using spring saml to integrate with a third party IDP server.

We inserted 2 X.509 certs one for signature and the other for encryption, and one SSL cert from IDP as public key inside java key-store.

**Environment:**

**Java Version:** 1.7

**Spring Version:** 4.3.7.RELEASE

**Spring Security Version:** 4.2.2.RELEASE

**spring-security-saml2-core:** 1.0.2.RELEASE

**Error Description:**

After user authenticated from IDP server, the IDP server redirect this user to our SP, and send back the artifact. The error was happening when we trying to send the artifactResolve back to IDP server.

The error: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null

The following are code snippet of spring security configuration and error logs.

**Spring Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
    @Bean
    public MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager() {
        return new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
        return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new SAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource storeFile = loader.getResource("classpath:/saml/project.jks");
        String storePass = "password";  
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();

        passwords.put("project", "password");
        passwords.put("project.sign", "password");
        // passwords.put("project.ssl", "password");
        String defaultKey = "project";


        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }



    // Setup TLS Socket Factory
    @Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
        return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
    }

    @Bean
    public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
        return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
        Object[] args = {"https", socketFactoryProtocol()};
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }

    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setLocal(true);
        extendedMetadata.setAlias("project");
        extendedMetadata.setSecurityProfile("metaiop");
        extendedMetadata.setSslSecurityProfile("metaiop");

        extendedMetadata.setSigningKey("project.sign");
        extendedMetadata.setEncryptionKey("project");
        extendedMetadata.setTlsKey("project.ssl");

        extendedMetadata.setRequireArtifactResolveSigned(false);
        extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutRequestSigned(false);
        extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutResponseSigned(false);
        //Turn off Idp discovery
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
        return extendedMetadata;
    }

    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/userLogin");
        return idpDiscovery;
    }


    @Bean
    public FilesystemMetadataProvider IdpFilesystemMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(new File(classLoader.getResource("metadata/idp.xml").getFile()));
        filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());

        return filesystemMetadataProvider;
    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration
        @Bean
        public ExtendedMetadataDelegate IdpExtendedMetadataProvider()
                throws MetadataProviderException {
            ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = 
                    new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(IdpFilesystemMetadataProvider());
            extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
            extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
            return extendedMetadataDelegate;
        }

    @Bean
    public FilesystemMetadataProvider SpFilesystemMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(new File(classLoader.getResource("metadata/sp_stg.xml").getFile()));
        filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
        return filesystemMetadataProvider;
    }


    // SP Metadata configuration
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate SPExtendedMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = 
                new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(SpFilesystemMetadataProvider(), extendedMetadata());
        // extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
        // extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }




    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
        providers.add(IdpExtendedMetadataProvider());
        providers.add(SPExtendedMetadataProvider());
        CachingMetadataManager cachingMetadataManager = new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
        cachingMetadataManager.setHostedSPName("http://SPdomain/projectstg");
        cachingMetadataManager.setDefaultIDP("https://IDPdomain/FIM/IDPFed/saml20");
        return cachingMetadataManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
                new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
        return failureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }

    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = 
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                logoutHandler());
    }

    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
    }

    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile = 
                new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
        MetadataManager metadataManager = null;
        try {
            providers.add(IdpExtendedMetadataProvider());
            metadataManager = new MetadataManager(providers);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        artifactResolutionProfile.setMetadata(metadataManager);
        metadataManager.refreshMetadata();
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    /**
     * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
     * 
     * @return Filter chain proxy
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"), samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"), samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"), metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"), samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"), samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"), samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"), samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
     * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
     * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
     * 
     * @throws  Exception 
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     * 
     * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws  Exception 
     */
    @Override  
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable();
        http
            // .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http        
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/test")).authenticated();
        http
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     * 
     * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws  Exception 
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/css/**",
                    "/fonts/**",
                    "/image/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/dist/**");
    }

}
```

**Error Log:**

```
2017-06-21|10:17 42,975|http-nio-8080-exec-6|HttpConnection.java|DEBUG|Open connection to idpDomain:443
2017-06-21|10:17 42,990|http-nio-8080-exec-6|HttpMethodDirector.java|DEBUG|Closing the connection.
2017-06-21|10:17 42,990|http-nio-8080-exec-6|HttpMethodDirector.java|DEBUG|Method retry handler returned false. Automatic recovery will not be attempted
2017-06-21|10:17 42,990|http-nio-8080-exec-6|HttpConnection.java|DEBUG|Releasing connection back to connection manager.
2017-06-21|10:17 42,990|http-nio-8080-exec-6|MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java|DEBUG|Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=https://idpDomain]
2017-06-21|10:17 42,990|http-nio-8080-exec-6|IdleConnectionHandler.java|DEBUG|Adding connection at: 1498011462990
2017-06-21|10:17 42,991|http-nio-8080-exec-6|MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java|DEBUG|Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2017-06-21|10:17 42,991|http-nio-8080-exec-6|AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java|DEBUG|Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error de
coding incoming SAML message
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error decoding incoming SAML message
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: Could not decode artifact response message
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:126)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.doDecode(HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.java:94)
        at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:79)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: Error when sending request to artifact resolution service.
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.getArtifactResponse(ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:101)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
        at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
        at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.getArtifactResponse(ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl.java:99)
        ... 47 more
```

We have tried

```
@Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        TLSProtocolConfigurer tLSProtocolConfigurer = new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
        tLSProtocolConfigurer.setSslHostnameVerification("allowAll");
        return tLSProtocolConfigurer;
    }
```

and almost all solutions on stackoverflow about this error, but it didn't work.

@Vladimír Schäfer we need your advice, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the SSL protocol that your Idp is using, if they are using TLSv1.2 then JDK version need to be upgraded to JDK8 as JDK8 HTTPClient default using TLSv1.2 but JDK7 using TLSv1